# How accurate Terrains are created in unity using height-map of actual location?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, unity3d-terrain

I'm creating a terrain in Unity using Terrain Toolbox with the help of a height-map of real locations downloaded from various tools available online. I want to know how accurately the depth and height of actual locations this tool can generate such as Mountains and rivers. How much sculpting is needed to smooth the jittery map it created based on the parameters we pass during the creation of this height-map. I'm attaching a screenshot of the settings I used.

Kindly, let me if something is not in my comprehension here or question is not framed adequately well.

Thanks in advance

[Screenshot of "Terrain Toolbox" settings for terrain creation(click this link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qj0F.png)

I created the terrain using the "Terrain Toolbox" with the above settings mentioned in the image.
Then I sculpted to remove and fix the jittery noise in the terrain and then sculpted the river for more visibility.

Comment: I don't see any image ... also don't know that tool in specific but a) Unity uses `float` which has of course some limitations in precision .. and b) I'd claim it mainly depends on the data you are feeding it with ... of course if you "smooth out" things .. this for sure also mans some precision loss to a certain extend .. what is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use heightmap export function.
In fact, I think it is impossible to great mountain and river completely by hand using any tools.

Do you know about DEM(digital elevation model) data?
In uniy3d, you can create terrain like earth by importing DEM data as heightmap.

After importing terrain, you can modify height, shape and etc.
After finished modifying, you can exporting the terrain information as heightmap type.

In heightmap file, the height is saved as 16bit short integer type.
For example you want to know the height of center position with 3600x3600 resolution terrain, calculate the offset in heightmap file.

The offset is 3600*(3600/2)+3600/2.
And go to the offset position and read 16bit integer.
You can use tools such as winhex.

You can see the export button on heightmap list of the inspection dialogue of terrain.